# AWS Lightsail Node JS Express Server Not Working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have launched an AWS Lightsail Bitnami Node JS instance. I have taken the following steps:

`mkdir /home/bitnami/stack/apps/`
`cd /home/bitnami/stack/apps/`
`git clone url`

`touch /opt/bitnami/apps/appname/conf/httpd-prefix.conf`
Add to file:
`Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/appname/conf/httpd-app.conf"`

`touch /opt/bitnami/apps/appname/conf/httpd-app.conf`
Add to file:
`ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/`
`ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/`

Add to this file: `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf`
this: `Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/appname/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"`

Restart apache server: `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache`

cd into `appname`
`npm install`
`node server.js`

When I navigate to the ip address it is still displaying the default bitnami file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. Instead of:

Adding to this file: `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf`
this: `Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/appname/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"`

Add to this file: `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf`
this: `Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/appname/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"`